# Returning a query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x

I'm not sure why I get an error when I call this function. The output I want to get is this.

Can anyone please help me fix this?

#### Desired Output

```
 ('BIOA01H3F', '26', '17-12-19', '9:00')
```

#### Code:

```
def get_course_time(db, course):
    ''' Return the course number, ID, the date and start time of the given 
        course's exam for all sections. Note there are only multiple sections if 
        the course IDs are different. '''

    return (run_query(db, '''SELECT ID, date, StartTime Where course?'''(course)))
```

#### Error:

```
return (run_query(db, '''SELECT ID, date, StartTime Where course = 
    ?'''(course)))
builtins.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after the end of the triple quotes.

Note that even if you fix this, you will then get another error because your SQL query is malformed. You need an equals sign.

You also have two sets of unnecessary parentheses.

```
 return run_query(db, '''SELECT ID, date, StartTime Where course = ?''', (course))
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed it, but I get this print("exams.db", "BIOA01H3F")
exams.db BIOA01H3F instead of this ('BIOA01H3F', '26', '17-12-19', '9:00')